# invoke flash click event from javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

i have a flash object in my html file

```
<embed id="ZeroClipboardMovie_1" src="/assets/811871e8/ZeroClipboard.swf" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100" height="38" name="ZeroClipboardMovie_1" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="id=1&amp;width=100&amp;height=38" wmode="transparent">
```

how can i make click event on this object when a html `button` is clicked for example ?

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear @MihaiIorga ... nope html button or java script code

Comment: You can communicate between java script and actionscript through External interfaces you can add event listeners in the actionscript side and on event you can call the java script functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose (invoke) your flash functions from javascript by using the ExternalInterface class and adding a callback.

AS3 (flash) code:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback('nameForJStoCall',flashFunctionName);
```

JS code:

```
document.getElementById('ZeroClipboardMovie_1').nameForJStoCall(yourParametersIfNeeded);
```

For more detailed examples:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

### You cannot however

tell flash to dispatch true click events externally (for security reasons). Things like invoking fullscreen mode, or a FileReference box will not work unless an element is actually clicked in flash.